# Navigating between the different areas in Xcode with a keyboard

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

[image: Xcode screenshot highlighting two tabs in the left hand panel (Project Navigator and Issue Navigator), the main code editor, and the scroll bar overview]

(By way of background I have been helping a local blind child learn coding. He's switching schools from a Windows based school to a Mac based school so I am trying to familiarise myself with VoiceOver on the Mac.)

Using just the keyboard (and with VoiceOver running) how do I switch focus between Xcode's main editing area, the project navigator, the issues navigator, and the scroll bar overview (we sometimes end up in the last one by accident!)

Comment: I originally asked this [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375380/142445) (and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250862306)) but I have just remembered that IDE specific questions are OK for SO. In fact Ask Different has [1,139](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcode) questions tagged 'xcode' while Stack Overflow has [135.4K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcuts you are looking for are the following

- The project navigator is: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>  (Cmd-1)
- The issues navigator is: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>  (Cmd-5)
- Main Editing area is (once you have selected a file in the issues or
  project navigator):

  - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>  (Cmd-J) and, after
    release, <kbd>↵</kbd> (Return) or
  - <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (Opt-Cmd-`)
- The Mini Map: <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Ctrl-Cmd-Shft-M)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've ended up cross-posting this [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375380/142445). If you want to copy-and-paste your answer there too I'll accept it there